# redirect with .htaccess a dynamic URL to a new static page

Tags: .htaccess, url, dynamic, redirect

How can I redirect with .htaccess a dynamic URL to a new static page, i.e. pages like:

```
/page2.php?view=preview&image=33&category=2
/page2.php?view=thumbnailList&category=1
/page2.php?view=thumbnailList&category=3
```

etc, to:

```
/index.php/photo-gallery
```

There are many pages like the 3 examples on top (and theyt are indexed by Google) and I would like to redirect all the pages which start with /page2.php? to the new location.

Comment: Would it be better if you use: /photo-gallery instead or you need to use /index.php/photo-gallery?

Comment: I am on Joomla and the /index.php/stays like that - I guess could be a work around that. What I wanted is the syntax to define with wildcard any page "page2.php?" followed by anthing.

Comment: I would recommend to use mod-rewrite. I am not familiar with Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (if you use apache).

Comment: I use apache, I tried several samples from the forum. What I wanted is the syntax how to define with wildcard "page2.php?" followed by anything. Thanks.